# Add favicon icon in media item

Tags: sxa

Is it possible to add favicon icon on media library items in Sitecore 9.
When we are trying to open any media item through page such as opening a .pdf link on new tab then favicon icon does not show.

We have added favicon icon on website level under below path:

```
/sitecore/content/Tenant/Site/Settings
```

Comment: I don't think that's possible. Browsers will just look for `/favicon.ico` url I'm afraid

Comment: embed the .pdf or media items and adding meta is an option, I guess.

Comment: Is it resolved in sitecore 9.2 or above version ?